# VS Code MarkdownString Won't Display Links

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been working on a custom extension for Visual Studio Code recently and am trying to show a link to the user when hovering over a specific phrase but it hasn't been working. The hover shows up but the link isn't "actionable".

My extension is registering a HoverProvider and is returning a new Hover object which contains a string with a link inside of it like so:

```
return new vscode.Hover({language: 'markdown', value: '[test-link](https://www.google.com)'});
```

I've tried switching the language between "markdown" and "HTML", but in either case, although the link was in the correct format, it was never actionable. I suspect this is because the value being fed in as a parameter to the Hover constructor is a [MarkdownString](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-namemarkedstringaspan-classcodeitem-id1107markedstringspan) which has the following note:

> Note that markdown strings will be sanitized - that means html will be
> escaped.

I could've sworn I've seen this feature elsewhere in VS Code like in a `package.json` file where a link to a repository was shown when hovering over a dependency name, but I can't seem to find a working example.

Here's an example of what the hover looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to get this feature working?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```js
    let disposable1 = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
        provideHover(document, position, token) {
            const word = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
            const searchOptions = {
                query: word
            };

            const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[test-link](https://www.google.com)`);

            contents.isTrusted = true;
            return new vscode.Hover(contents);
        }
    });
```

Note that `new Hover()` has this signature:

```js
new Hover(contents: MarkdownString | MarkedString | Array<MarkdownString | MarkedString>, range?: Range): Hover
```

See [Hover api reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Hover).

You were trying to give it an object (with a `language` key).

---

With vscode v1.61 this will also work within the provider:

```js
const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[test-link](https://www.google.com)`);

contents.appendMarkdown("<a href='https://www.google.com'>test-link2</a>");
contents.supportHtml = true;

contents.isTrusted = true;
return new vscode.Hover(contents);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954180/836330 for more on newly supported html tags.