# How to apply styling and html tags on hover message with vscode API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to style or format the hover message with `MarkdownString` but it always resulted in empty space or escaped everything but I found out that you can use `span` to style it but you can only apply `color` and `background-color` with this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/97793).

Right now, it's ugly as plain text can be, and even using table markdown is not working. Is there a way to improve this?

[image: Plain text hover message]

I'm writing it as follow:

```js
const markdown = new MarkdownString(`<p> Some label: <code>${value}</code></p>`);
markdown.isTrusted = true;

return new Hover(markdown, range);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With v1.61 you will have more `markdownString` options.  There will be suport for these html tags:

`allowedTags: ['ul', 'li', 'p', 'code', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'hr', 'em', 'pre', 'table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tr', 'th', 'td', 'div', 'del', 'a', 'strong', 'br', 'img', 'span'],`

So with `b`, `h1`, etc. you can get a bit of extra "styling".

```
/**
  * Indicates that this markdown string can contain raw html tags. Default to false.
  *
  * When `supportHtml` is false, the markdown renderer will strip out any raw html tags
  * that appear in the markdown text. This means you can only use markdown syntax for rendering.
  *
  * When `supportHtml` is true, the markdown render will also allow a safe subset of html tags
  * and attributes to be rendered. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/6d2920473c6f13759c978dd89104c4270a83422d/src/vs/base/browser/markdownRenderer.ts#L296
  * for a list of all supported tags and attributes.
*/
  supportHtml?: boolean;
```

Some sample code:

```js
const value = "Jello";

const content = new vscode.MarkdownString(`<span style="color:#000;background-color:#fff;">Howdy there.</span>`);
content.appendMarkdown(`<p><b> Some label: <code>${value}</code></b></p>`)
content.supportHtml = true;

content.isTrusted = true;

return new vscode.Hover(content, new vscode.Range(position, position));
```

In my testing you can still only use

`<span style="color:#000;background-color:#fff;">`

with no other styles but `color` and `background-color`.

- You can also use this: `<span style='color:var(--vscode-charts-green);'>` where `charts.green` is a reference to a `ThemeColor`.  So you could define your own themeColor in the package.json `contributes` `color` options and use it in your hoverProvider.  Or use one of the built-in themeColors from [vscode api reference: them colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).  See [Allow use of --vscode-XXX color variables in  style in Markdown](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176064).

---

Here are a few options that work for me to do styling, markdown tables, code blocks, etc.:

```js
vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
    provideHover(document, position, token) {
        
        // a markdown table, wrapping in a styled span did not work
        // had to style each "cell" separately
        // html entity &nbsp; works

        const markdown = new vscode.MarkdownString(`
|    <span style="color:#ff0;background-color:#000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Table&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>|    Header     |
|    :----:    |    :----:     |
|first cell    |second cell  |
|third cell    |<span style="color:#f00;background-color:#fff;">&nbsp;&nbsp;fourth cell&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>  |
        \n\n\n`);  // the newline is necessary for any following appends to work correctly, multiple newlines are reduced to one
        
        const styledString = `<span style="color:#fff;background-color:#666;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NASA code follows:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>`;

        const codeBlock = `const a = 12;
if (a) return;`;    // any preceding tabs will be rendered in a template literal, so flush left

        // const codeBlock2 = `const c = 12;\nif (c) return;`;  // works, alternate form with newline

        markdown.appendText("______________________________\n");  // a fake separator
        markdown.appendMarkdown(styledString);
        markdown.appendCodeblock(codeBlock, "javascript");
        markdown.appendMarkdown(
`**Bold Text**
* some note
* another note
* final note`
        );

        markdown.isTrusted = true;

        return new vscode.Hover(markdown, new vscode.Range(position, position));
    }
```

[image: hover styling demo]

- Note: the markdown table doesn't get any cell or table dividers for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, this could be as far as we can get for styling. Thank you for this. Totally appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried `<p>` and `<code>` elements too.  They didn't work.

Comment: Yeah that PR I included only allowed span with color

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Need to format some text on the hover but can't. When is v1.61 going to be released? npm still lists it as v1.60

Comment: @EdwinSamuelJonathan Expected release date for v1.61 is October 6, 2021.

Comment: @Mark appreciate it

Comment: @Mark Hey, Could you take a look at my Q here? Any way we could execute a <script> in markdowns? I have got the img preview on hover any way to get the dims? Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716516/vscode-extension-api-how-to-obtain-the-properties-of-an-image-file