# How to add styled text in vscode.MarkdownString

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to implement coloured text in vscode.MarkdownString?

I'm trying to implement popup like in vscode when you just hover line of code.

[image]

And I want to add different colours for text in my popup.

Right now I'm using code like this

```
const decorations: vscode.DecorationOptions[] = [];
const markdownString = new vscode.MarkdownString();
markdownString.supportHtml = true;
markdownString.appendMarkdown('markdown string');

decorations.push({
   range: new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(lineNumber, 0), new vscode.Position(lineNumber, 0)),
   hoverMessage: markdownString
});
```

I tried different html tags, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: that part of the Markdown is a literal block with languageid, that is syntax highlighted, VSC-core has a larger API than the extension API

Comment: @rioV8 so it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you are using this, but in my testing here is the full code I used (js not typescript):

```js
const decorations = [];
const markdownString = new vscode.MarkdownString();
markdownString.supportHtml = true;
markdownString.appendMarkdown('<span style="color:#f4f40b;background-color:#666;">markdown string</span>');
markdownString.appendText('\n');
markdownString.appendMarkdown('<span style="color:#f00;background-color:#fff;">below markdown string</span>');

const lineNumber = 1;

decorations.push({
   range: new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(lineNumber, 0), new vscode.Position(lineNumber, 3)),
   hoverMessage: markdownString
});

const decorationsOptions = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({color: "red"});
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.setDecorations(decorationsOptions, decorations);
```

Wrap your markdownString text with `<span style="color:#f4f40b;background-color:#666;"> some text here </span>`.
I don't think you can put much in `style` attribute other than `color` and `background`.

[image: markdown with colors for decorations]

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67954180/836330 for code blocks and table styling - it was for a hoverProvider but that doesn't make a difference.